# Maven maven-replacer-plugin Issue, in removal of the braces after the replace is done

Tags: maven, replace

I am using the maven-replacer-plugin (https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/wiki/UsageGuide).
I am using the use-case explained "Single file replacement using a tokenValueMap".

I am not able to get the tokens replaced properly in the source file that is having these tokens.

Requirement
I need to generate an XML file with field values for the tokens, taken from a properties file.

The XML file, is in the format as below.

**XML_DEV.txt**

```
 <field>
     <name>HTTP/Server</name>
     <value>${Server}</value>
 </field>
 <field>
     <name>HTTP/Port</name>
     <value>${Port}</value>
 </field>
```

I have the values of these placeholder variables (Server and Port) defined in separate properties files for each environment (DEV, QA, PROD).

**Application_DEV.properties**

```
Server=DEV_Application_Server1
Port=8081
```

**Application_QA.properties**

```
Server=QA_Application_Server11
Port=8082
```

I am using ${..} to identify the tokens in the Source XML file (XML_DEV.txt).
I am using the tokenValueMap to identify the list of tokens and the values that needs to be replaced for these tokens.

**What is happenning so far..**

I am able to get the values replaced, but the ${} braced is not getting removed in the output file generated.
Example for QA replacement.
**Input** (sample from file XML_DEV.txt)

```
 <field>
     <name>HTTP/Server</name>    
     <value>${Server}</value>
 </field>
```

is being changed to

**Output** (sample from file XML_DEV_mod.txt)

```
 <field>
     <name>HTTP/Server</name>
     <value>${QA_Application_Server11}</value>
 </field>
```

All tokens are getting changed, but the '${ }' is still present in the output file as above.
My POM file used is as below. Please let me know if I am missing something, to force Maven to remove the ${ }.

My Current POM file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <executions>                
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>                    
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <file>${inputFile}</file>
                <tokenValueMap>DEV_properties.txt</tokenValueMap>
                <outputFile>${outFileName}</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**DEV_properties.txt (token value map)**

```
Server=DEV_Application_Server1
Port=8081
inputFile=XML_DEV.txt
outFileName=XML_DEV_mod.txt
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks in Advance

-Raghu

PS:
I had an earlier post (query) regarding this Issues, where I was suggested to use Filtering to solve this Requirement. 
I am still working on the filter option (though I have not been successful so far), when I found this replacer-plugin to get the tokens replaced.

[Maven - Solution to replace variables in a XML file after fetching their values from a properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010037/maven-solution-to-replace-variables-in-a-xml-file-after-fetching-their-values)

Answer (score 1):

An update,
I was able to solve the Issue by using `<delimiters>`, and when I used `%` as the token, as below.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <executions>                
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>                    
        </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
        <delimiters>
          <delimiter>%</delimiter> 
        </delimiters>
        <file>${inputFile}</file>
        <tokenValueMap>DEV_properties.txt</tokenValueMap>
        <outputFile>${outFileName}</outputFile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This could change the input file containing tokens as below

```
 <field>
     <name>HTTP/Server</name>    
     <value>%Server%</value>
 </field>
```

to

```
 <field>
     <name>HTTP/Server</name>
     <value>QA_Application_Server11</value>
 </field>
```

as required.

I would have loved to have `${Var}` changed as mentioned in the problem.
But this solves the requirement.

Thanks to the below post,
    [Managing Google Maps API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442545/managing-google-maps-api-keys/5985674#5985674)

Regards

-Raghu